# Need help troubleshooting MIPS code to count lowercase letters

Tags: string, char, addition, mips

I wrote this code in MIPS to count the # of lowercase letters input by a user:

```
.data
msg1: .asciiz
count_lower: .space 41
.text
.globl main
main:
la $a0, msg1 #load address of msg1 to store string
li $a1, 100 #msg1 is 100 bytes
li $v0, 8 #syscall for read str
syscall

add $s1, $0, $0 #interger to print later
la $t0, count_lower 
sw $a0, 0($t0) #store input string in $t0
loop:
lb $t1, 0($t0) #load char from $t0
beqz $t1, exit #if no more chars, exit
blt $t1, 'a', else #This line and line below are for if char is not lowercase
bgt $t1, 'z', else
addi $s1, $s1, 1 #if char is lowercase, +1 to $s1
sll $t0, $t0, 8 #shift one byte to get to next char
sll $t1, $t1, 8 #shift one byte to get to next char

else:
sll $t0, $t0, 8 #shift one byte to get to next char
sll $t1, $t1, 8 #shift one byte to get to next char
j loop #jump back to loop

exit:
move $a0, $s1 #move interge to print into $a0
li $v0, 1 #print interger in $a0
syscall
li $v0, 10 #exit 
syscall
```

But when I run it, all it does it print the integer "0" no matter what string is input. Can anyone help me troubleshoot? I wrote comments in the code to explain my thought proccess.

EDIT:

```
1 .data
2 msg1: .space 100
3 .text
4 .globl main
5 main:
6 li $v0, 8 #syscall for read str
7 la $a0, msg1 #load address of msg1 to store string
8 li $a1, 100 #msg1 is 100 bytes
9 move $t0, $a0 #save user input to $t0
10 syscall
11 add $s1, $0, $0 #interger to print later
12 add $t1, $0, $0 #initialize $t1
13 loop:
14 sb $t0, 0($t1) #store rightmost char into memory 0
15 lb $t1, 0($t0) #load char from memory 0 into $t1
16 beqz $t1, exit #if no more chars, exit
17 blt $t1, 'a', else #This line and line below are for if char is not       
18 lowercase
19 bgt $t1, 'z', else
20 addi $s1, $s1, 1 #if char is lowercase, +1 to $s1
21 srl $t0, $t0, 8 #shift one byte to get to next char
22 add $t1, $0, $0 #re-initialize $t1
23 j loop #jump back to loop
24 else:
25 srl $t0, $t0, 8 #shift one byte to get to next char
26 add $t1, $0, $0 #re-initialize $t1
27 j loop #jump back to loop
28 
29 exit:
30 move $a0, $s1 #move interge to print into $a0
31 li $v0, 1 #print interger in $a0
32 syscall
33 li $v0, 10 #exit 
34 syscall
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't do what you seem to think it does:

```
sw $a0, 0($t0) #store input string in $t0
```

That instruction only stores the *address of* the string at `($t0)` (i.e. in the first 4 bytes of `count_lower`).

I really don't see why you need two buffers for this. Just read the characters from the same buffer that you specified for syscall 8.

Also, your declaration of `msg1` is incorrect. Your comment says `#msg1 is 100 bytes`, but your declaration is `msg1: .asciiz`, which certainly doesn't reserve 100 bytes. That should be changed to `msg1: .space 100`.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for answering. I edited my code (you can see my edit in the original question) to reflect your suggestions. I'm getting an error in line 14 now with the `lb` instruction. I think I understand why, though. What I WANT it to do is to load the first byte in the `$t0` register but what it's actually doing is loading a byte from memory `($t0+0)`, right? How do I get it to load a byte from the register instead of from memory?

Comment: Okay regarding my last comment, I thought I came up with the solution and edited my question to reflect that. In line 14 I chose to store the rightmost 8 bits from `$t0` into memory, then load those bits from memory into another register, but I'm still getting a `line 14: Runtime exception at 0x00400020: address out of range 0x00000000` error, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: It's fairly obvious why that happens: `add $t1, $0, $0 #initialize $t1` / `sb $t0, 0($t1)`

Comment: It's not obvious to me since I just started learning this stuff last week, and that comment didn't really explain it to me. I did something else and figured it out, but thanks anyway for answering.

Comment: `add $t1, $0, $0` sets `$t1` to 0. `sb $t0, 0($t1)` attempts to write to memory at the address contained in `$t1`, which you just set to 0.